# UWP : Best practice for device watchers inside a background task in a UWP app

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app which uses background tasks. I have a requirement to use a device watcher for HID and for Bluetooth devices inside this background task. Is it better to use 2 watchers inside the same background task that will look for different devices or would it be better to separate the two? Are there any repercussions(for example: power) of having different watchers inside the same background task?

Comment: The repercussion is that you have a background task that is continuously running. Instead, use a DeviceWatcherTrigger. This tells the system to run a task when there is activity on a device watcher. You can configure the device watcher to trigger for both HID and Bluetooth devices by using the `OR` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no known issue for using them together. So I think you could put them in the same task.

Just talk from my point view, if there isn't much same code for these two different features, I would separate them into different parts. This will make it easy to maintain these two features when you have different requirements.